# onserverclick does not get triggered at code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this function in my code behind

```
       protected void ShowDocument(int id, object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT Data FROM FileUploader2", con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        bytes = (byte[])reader["Data"];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And I am calling it on my aspx as follows:

```
  <input type="button"  ID="btnView" runat="server" value="View" 
    onserverclick="ShowDocument(id)" />
```

But it is giving me error saying name id does not exist in the current context. What am i doing wrong?
And if i just write ShowDocument then

No overload for 'ShowDocument' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: Where's your 'id' in the aspx file? Does it exist?

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are getting is correct in the assumption that id doesn't exist in your current context. 
When the onclick event fires, your id field doesn't exist inside the .aspx file and therefore cannot be passed into the method as a parameter.

Have a look at this example of how to pass parameters into your onclick functions:

in your aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="test" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("product.ProductId")%>' CommandName="ThisBtnClick" OnClick="MyBtnHandler" />
```

in code behind

```
void MyBtnHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button btn = (Button)sender;
   switch (btn.CommandName)
   {
      case "ThisBtnClick":
         DoWhatever(btn.CommandArgument.ToString());
         break;
      case "ThatBtnClick":
         DoSomethingElse(btn.CommandArgument.ToString());
         break;
   }
}
```